Euler integration with quaternions results in half angle
if you use one of the approaches of Euler integration with quaternions to integrate the angular velocity, the result is always only half the angle. Shouldn't it be the same as in the translational case: x = x + v*dt?
In the picture is a simple example, with a constant angular velocity around the z-axis and I use the "direct multiplication method" from
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00707-013-0914-2
but also the other approaches always lead to half an angle step. I know that for the rotation of a vector r with quaternions, as in r´=qrq-1, q is used with phi/2 and it works fine (I guess due to the double multiplication) but why is it different here?


atan2 gives you a HALF of angle, quaternion stores half rotation angle.
